# Как проверить работает ли open server

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть database.json файл. Как проверить работает ли post метод? Включаю сервер, но не дает ответа(respond). Делаю Fetch запрос.

Comment: А у вас есть сервер, который будет обрабатывать POST запрос?

Comment: Да кажется есть. Написано используется Apache

Comment: Я в этом деле новичок